# how to create objects based on key value pair

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

Say you have the collection of key/value pair. for e.g. : -

```
dictionary<string,string> myObjectToBeCreated = new dictionary<string,string>();
myObjectToBeCreated.Add("int","myIntObject");
myObjectToBeCreated.Add("string","myStringObject");
myObjectToBeCreated.Add("employee","myEmployeeObject");
```

Now, How can you create the object of int named myIntObject using myObjectToBeCreated. something like this: -

```
int myIntObject;
string myStringObject;
Employee myEmployeeObject = new Employee();
```

Note: You have just the collection. This collection is having the dataTypes and objectnames. How can you create the object of those dataType with the specific names(defined in dictionary). You can pass this collection (MyObjectsToBeCreated in any method you want to). But at the end you should get the object of type (specified in dictionary).

You can use any design pattern say ***factory/dependency/builder***. Or even you are free to achieve the above w/o using pattern.

Comment: What result do you expect? Dictionary of objects?

Comment: Uhm, no problem getting instances of the given types, but you really can't use the name for anything, unless you want to generate code?

Comment: @SergRogovtsev, nope objects/object. Say you had passed just one key/value pair in the method which returns specified object of type in key/value pair

Comment: @SteenT, how can you get instance of given types even....?

Comment: @anilpurswani Please give exact signature of method you need to implement. I suppose it has one parameter of type `IDictionary<string, string>`, but what's its return type?

Comment: @SergRogovtsev, I don't have any method signature in my mind....as I am searching the way out to accomplish that.

Comment: @anilpurswani if you don't have method signature in mind, you don't know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev, well we got the dictionary with the object types and names. but now we need to develop a method/mechanism through which we can create the object of specific type and name.

Comment: What do you mean by "object with name"? Objects in CLR have no name.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev, ("int","myIntObject")....here the type is int and objectname is myIntObject.....so at the end I should get ... int myIntObject

Comment: `int myIntObject` is a locally declared variable. You can't emit local variables at runtime.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev, thats what the problem we are facing as of now....there is no way to emit local variables at runtime....

Comment: That's why what you're doing is just a trying to solve wrong problem. The won't be a solution for that. You should tell us *what* you're trying to solver, *why* do you need dynamically emitted local variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using just the class name for custom class won't be enough. You need the whole namespace.

Then assuming you have a parameterless constructor for your type you can use

```
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(strNamespace + strType))
```

or

```
Activator.CreateInstance(strNamespace, strType)
```

Comment: Although your first example i.e - "Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(strNamespace + strType))", seems close to my query so +1 for the same. But it still lack the declaration of variablename (objectname). How can you assign the return value of CreateInstance to the variable "myIntObject, myStringObject" etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Type instead of string:

```
Dictionary<Type, object> yourObjects = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
yourObjects[typeof(int)] = 5;
yourObjects[typeof(string)] = "bamboocha";


var integer = (int)yourObjects[typeof(int)];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myObjects = new Dictionary<string, Object>();

foreach (var pair in myObjectToBeCreated)
{
    var strNamespace = //set namespace of 'pair.Key'
    myObjects.Add(pair.Value, Activator.CreateInstance(strNamespace, pair.Key));
}

// and using it
var myEmployeeObject = (Employee)myObjects["myEmployeeObject"];
```

Comment: Ria, Employee class is not exposed to the client. As they have the string collection which contains the class name, but they don't have exposure to classes. If it was there then there is no need to use any complex mechanism to create object, I would have rather created using Employee myEmployee = new Employee. But I can't do that as Employee class is not exposed to the client. Note: All other types used in the example are just to make it simple. but in practice, we are going to get the class name as a string and the name of the objectvariable to be created.